Canonical conics pulling back to polynomials on rational normal curve
(In following all schemes are formed over $\Bbb C$)
Let $C:=\nu_d(\Bbb P^1)$ the rational normal curve obtained via $d$-folded Veronese map $\nu_d: \Bbb P^1 \to \Bbb P^d$. The quadrics on $\Bbb P^d$ are pulled back to homogeneous $2d$ polynomials on $\Bbb P^1$ via induced pullback map $\nu_d(2): H^0(\Bbb P^d, O(2)) \to H^0(\Bbb P^1, O(2d))$.
Question: Is it possible (and how) to find a "canonically choosen" left inverse of this map, ie to associate "canonically" to each  homog degree-$2d$ polynomial - which up to scaling is determined by datum of $2d$ points on $\Bbb P^1$ - a quadric on $\Bbb P^d$ pulling back to it? Note, the question is focussed on if one can do it "canonically".
Geometrically this asks if for prescribed $2d$ points $p_1,...,p_{2d}$ on $C$ we can find a "canonical" quadric $Q(C) \subset \Bbb P^d$ such that $C \cap Q(C)=\{p_1,...,p_{2d}\}$.
Motivation: I not fully understand what is meant by "distinguished/ natural choice" as claimed in these notes - see p 94ff, Example 20.3 paragraph - there is discussed
cases $d=2,3$.
Case $d=2$ appears only understandable in light of additional fact that smooth quadrics in $\Bbb P^2$ are rational normal curves and it is well known that these are uniquely determined by general $2+3$ points. Although, wouldn't we have still one degree of freedom as we pin down only $4$ and not $2+3$ points? But for $d=3$ and bigger this trick not works as quadrics are no more rational normal curves.
So I not understand in which way there exist a canonical construction associating to a homog degree-$2d$ polynomial -aka up to scaling $2d$ points on $\Bbb P^1$ - a "canonical choice" of a quadric in $\Bbb P^d$ pulling back to it.
#Added later in order to emphasize where I see the problem/ principal objection of this question: As Jason Starr and Sasha exposed the splitting exists from abstract reasons. My point was that the excerpt in Example 20.3 from linked notes suggests - at least that's how I understood this part - that one can perform this lift "explicitly" and "naturally"; in the sense of if one picks a homogeneous $2d$ homogen polynomial $f$ on $\Bbb P^1$, then one can pick "naturally" a quadric in $\Bbb P^d$ lifting it.
"Naturally" in which sense? Clearly that's not unique: For $d=2$ the space of quadrics lifting $f$ is at least $2$- dimensional. But the excerpt suggests - if I understand that part correctly - that one can still pick a "natural or canonical" lift of $f$. This should boil down to that up to scaling $f$ is determined by $2d$ points - its zeroes.
Could it be clarified how this "natural" choice is realized "by hand"? For sake of simplicity its ok to focus on cases $d=2,3$ as linked script does.

The Lie algebra of the automorphism group of $\mathbb{P}^1$ is $\mathfrak{sl}_2$.  Since this is semisimple, it is possible to find a splitting of this surjection that is compatible with the (universal cover of the) automorphism group scheme of $\mathbb{P}^1$.

@JasonStarr: Yes, that's another abstract argument for existence of the split. I was wondering if one can on "low level" - in spirit of the Example 20.3 in linked notes suggesting - "by hand" associate to a picked degree-$2d$ homog polynomial on $\Bbb P^1$ - so as data of $ 2d$ points -a quadric lifting it. Say for sake of simplicity $d=2$. Can one do it explicitly?

There is a unique $\mathrm{SL}_2$-invariant (hence canonical) lift. Indeed, with respect to the natural $\mathrm{SL}_2$-action on $\mathbb{P}^1$, the ambient space for the Veronese embedding is the space $\mathbb{P}(\mathrm{Sym}^d(V))$, where $V$ is the standard representaion of $\mathrm{SL}_2$. The space of quadrics on this space is
$$
\mathrm{Sym}^2(\mathrm{Sym}^d(V)) \cong
\mathrm{Sym}^{2d}(V) \oplus \mathrm{Sym}^{2d-4}(V) \oplus \dots
$$
and the first summand in this decomposition gives a canonical lift.
Edit.
Explicitly this splitting is given by the composition
$$
\mathrm{Sym}^{2d}(V) \hookrightarrow
V^{\otimes 2d} =
V^{\otimes d} \otimes V^{\otimes d} \to
\mathrm{Sym}^{d}(V) \otimes \mathrm{Sym}^{d}(V) \to
\mathrm{Sym}^2(\mathrm{Sym}^{d}(V)),
$$
where the first arrow is the natural embedding and the last two are the natural projections.

Yes, that's the abstract existence argument. Can one do it "by hand on low level" a la what is seemingly suggested in Example 20.3 in linked notes. So say we take a degree-$2d$ homog polynomial on $\Bbb P^1$ - so equivltly a data of $ 2d$ points - and want pick "canonically" a quadric lifting it as in test suggested. Let for sake of simplicity $d=2$. Can one do it explicitly?

In other words, can one pick the "canonical" lifts - at least for small $d$ - explicitly/algorithmically if I give you some homogen $2d$ polynomial?

@user267839: I added an explanation about how to do this explicitly.

Thanks! Can this added part be visualized geometrically in following sense (say for $d=2$): Say $p_1,..., p_4 \in C \subset \Bbb P^2$ are arbitr $4$ point on our rat norm curve $C$ representing a homog deg $4$ polynomial on in it as vanishing locus. Then by cointing down imposed conditions (+ noting that on rat norm curves any tuple of distinct points are always in general position) there is a pencil of quadrics (ie parametrized by $\Bbb P^1$) intersecting with $C$ in exactly these $4$ points. If we interpret the splitting geometrically there should be always a continuous "canonical" choice

of such quadric inside the pencils $P({p_1, ...,p_4})$ when we vary $p_1,...,p_4$. Does this distinguished quadric have some "characteristic geometric feautures"? The "canonicality" of the splitting above suggest that in geometric terms this quadric should reflect also to be in certain sense "geometrically distinguished". Can one say more about its geometry?

I don't know how to characterize the equivariant lift geometrically.

Just a quick addendum to Sasha's answer, to make things even more concrete and elementary. If $P(x_1,x_2)$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $2d$ in $(x_1,x_2)$, the lift is given by the $d$-th polarization, in the language of 19th century classical invariant theory. Namely, it is the polynomial
$$
Q(x_1,x_2;y_1,y_2)=\frac{d!}{(2d)!}
\left(y_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+
y_2\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\right)^d P(x_1,x_2)\ .
$$
The latter is bihomogeneous of bidegree $(d,d)$ in the two pairs of variables $(x_1,x_2)$ and $(y_1,y_2)$. Moreover, it satisfies
$$
Q(x_1,x_2;y_1,y_2)=Q(y_1,y_2;x_1,x_2)
$$
and thus naturally lives in ${\rm Sym}^2({\rm Sym}^d(V))$. The construction is also ${\rm SL}_2$-equivariant.

Thanks! By ${\rm SL}_2$ equivariance of this construction you mean that if we denote this construction by $P \mapsto Q_P$, then for all $R \in {\rm SL}_2$ using induced ${\rm SL}2$ action from $V$ to ${\rm Sym}^{2d}(V)$ and ${\rm Sym}^2({\rm Sym}^d(V))$ we always have $R\cdot Q_P = Q{R \cdot P}$, right?

By the way, this would also give a nice geometric interpretation I was looking for: As up to scaling a deg $d$-polynomial on $\Bbb P^1$ is encoded by set ${p_1,...,, p_d}$ of its zeroes, this construction seem to produce exactly the unique quadric $Q \subset \Bbb P^d$ intersecting with $d$-Veronese embedding of $\Bbb P^1$ in these points with distinguished feature that every $A \in \rm SL_2$ permuting the $p_1,..., p_d$, restricts to an automorphism on $Q$ with resp the induced action

Pretty sure that Harris wanted to tell precisely this in the linked notes, thanks!

About equivariance, that's right. I didn't have time to think much about the point construction so hopefully what follows is not wrong. I think what you said is correct. The Veronese and the quadric generically intersect in $2d$ points, and if one is careful with the use of self-duality for $SL2$, the $Q_{R,P}$ should cut the Veronese at the points  corresponding to the homogeneous roots of $P$. This is not enough to define the quadric uniquely, if only because of the other summands. So one needs an extra condition for uniqueness. Not sure I digested the one you gave in terms of permuting..

..the points and automorphisms of $Q$. One condition which would do the job is that the Cayley operator $\Omega_{xy}$ hitting the bihomogeneous form should give a form of bidegree $(d-1,d-1)$ which vanishes identically.
